# RockShox Psylo oil replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, shocks

I have a Specialized bike that I haven't been using that I want to give to my sister. It's been sitting in my basement for about 5 years stored upside down. When I brought it up to my shop to do some maintenance I noticed the shock (RockShox Psylo) was leaking oil. I googled around to see how hard of a job this is to do myself and it looked pretty straight forward as there weren't any special tools. I did read that some shocks have specific specs for oil and this shock is a bit old so I don't know yet if I will be able to dig those specs up. Should I attempt to fix or should I have a tech do it?

Comment: Search for "Rockshox Psylo oil".... https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/yCV4_rHIL_OCKnPaTIArUGdVtqflfS9qXYVgzI6__6c/mtime:1372788192/sites/default/files/techdocs/02_04PsyloandDukeUTurn.pdf.   Needs 140cc of 5WT oil (for this model - what year is yours).

Comment: We can't tell you what a fork service will cost at your LBS, better to ring them and ask.   Assuming it was stored properly, and not ridden hard then put away dirty then it should be simple rebuild.  If it has drained all the oil then you might have a bigger job.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. I'm unsure what model I have. I will need to try to find the model year of the bike and will report back. The bike has never had a fork service before but it also wasn't ridden very often. I stored it in my basement for a long time upside down.

Comment: @JohnDrach The question is 5 months old - how did you get on with the fork?  Feel free to add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild manuals seem available (see link in comments). Figure out what year the fork is and google for the appropriate document. If you can't find it contact RockShox, they should be able to provide you with what you need.

Assuming the bike has not been ridden to the point where seals etc need replacing you should be able to just do a oil change.

If you have the tools and are confident you can do what the manual describes, go for it. If you mess up you can take it to the LSB.

Comment: I may give it a try

Comment: If it is leaking oil the seals may be shot. I wouldn't be surprised given the age of the fork. Changing the seals does require a special tool.

Comment: I've found a large socket or piece of PVC pipe perfect for installing fork seals.